# How to store an Excel file using Flask REST API

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I have been trying to implement a simple Flask REST API which would accept an Excel file and store it into a directory.

Below is the snippet I am using

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import abort
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/tasks/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_xlsx():
    file = request.files['ciq_file']
    if not file:
        return  jsonify({'error' : 'File is empty!'})

    fl_secure = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save('/data/prabir/t/testnew.xlsx', fl_secure)
    return jsonify({'status' : 'success'})
```

But, when I am trying to call this service, it is throwing `TypeError: an integer is required`

`(venv) [xyx@xyz t]$ curl -F 'ciq_file=@/data/prabir/somefile.xlsx' http://localhost:5000/tasks/add`

Curl command fails with the below error:

```
File "/data/prabir/t/app.py", line 35, in add_xlsx
    file.save('/data/prabir/t/testnew.xlsx', fl_secure)
  File "/data/prabir/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2803, in save
    copyfileobj(self.stream, dst, buffer_size)
  File "/data/TRpython/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 63, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "/data/TRpython/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 605, in read
    return self._file.read(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I am unable to figure out what could be the potential mistake I am doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `.save` method takes up to 2 arguments: `dst` and `buffer_size`.

- `dst` is either a string indicating the file path or a file object to write to.
- `buffer_size` is an integer that specifies the buffer size to use when writing the file.

Right now you are passing two strings: `'/data/prabir/t/testnew.xlsx'` and `fl_secure`.

You probably want to do this:

```
file.save('/data/prabir/t/' + fl_secure)
```

This will save the file to the path `/data/prabir/t/` with the original upload file name.

Comment: Thank you James! I really feel stupid. I had gone through the save but it didn't occur to me :)